# Elevated Priviliges for Startup Applications in Windows?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-vista, uac, elevation

Is there any way to configure application that requires administrator privilages (elevation) so it's automatically started with elevated privileges and does not request elevation on every startup?

For example, I have Riva Tuner that always starts with Windows. And it always asks for elevation via UAC. I need Riva Tuner to silently start with elevated privileges and without any message from user account control (without disabling it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/selectively-disable-uac-for-your-trusted-vista-applications/) article covers quite a few options of how to do this. Among them are:

- Using BeyondTrust in the Enterprise
- Use Task Manager to launch startup applications
- Use the Application Toolkit to disable UAC for selected application
- Switch off UAC (Not Recommended / Bad Practice)

The option to *Always run as administrator* available when Right Clicking and going to Properties will still cause a UAC prompt, it just forces the application to always launch as administrator.

The other option is to edit the local machine policy and allow administrators to launch applications without being prompted.

Answer (score 16):

The simplest and best way to do this is to set your application to be started when you log in, with **Task Scheduler** (Start search, or Administrative Tools -> Task Scheduler).

> 1. Check the "Run with highest privileges" box on the General tab.
> 2. On the Triggers tab, create a new trigger for when you log in.
> 3. On the Actions tab, create a new action to start your chosen
>      application.

This will launch your program as Administrator whenever you start up and log in.

Comment: Confirmed to be working on Windows 10. In triggers, select to "begin the task" "at startup".