# How do I allow programs that require admin rights to run at startup in Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, permissions, boot, uac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Elevated Priviliges for Startup Applications in Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/46/elevated-priviliges-for-startup-applications-in-vista)

I have several monitor/profile apps set to run at startup (Logitech Hardware stuff) that require elevated permissions.  Currently, when logging on, Vista blaocks them from running and requires my intervention to get them going.

I would like to avoid turning off UAC, since I have other users on this PC.

Is the a way to selectively allow these apps to run at startup with the required permissions?

Following added for clarity -

I have configured both applications to run at admin level, but because they are being run at startup (I believe in all cases from HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run registry key), Vista is blocking them from running.  So rather than just a popup waiting from my input to run, I get an icon in the system tray telling me that Windows has blocked these programs from running.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/46/elevated-priviliges-for-startup-applications-in-vista

Answer (score 5):

You can get round this problem by using Task Scheduler to run the programs at startup, as this allows you to do so with elevated permissions. See [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/window-on-windows/?p=616) for full details on how to do it.

Comment: This seems like the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

One way is to configure a shortcut (maybe the shortcut in the *Startup* directory in the start menu) to always start the program with Administrator rights:

Right click the shortcut --> *Properties* --> *Shortcut* tab --> *Advanced...* --> select *Run as Administrator*

Comment: I have them set to run as admin, but Windows is blocking them and I'm guessing that it's because they're startup apps with eleveated permissions.