# How can I make programs start at startup in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, boot

I have some programs I use a lot and would like them to start when I login to Vista.

**How can I make a program start when I login to Windows Vista?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can copy shortcuts to the programs you wish to run into the following directory:

> C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs\Startup

Comment: And for those wondering, this works for Windows 7, too!  I am happy to say.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist, what about Windows 10?

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb, I don't know yet!  Quite new to W10 at this point!

Comment: Tried it out, it does work on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

- Start System Configuration by pressing `Win + R` (to open Run). Type `msconfig` and give permission if needed. In the Startup tab check the program you want to start. If that doesn't work (the program might not be in the list of startup programs), try:
- Go to `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` (`Username` should be substituted for your username. Also note that `AppData` is a hidden directory). Make a shortcut to the program you want started and put the shortcut in the `Startup` directory.

The next time Vista starts the program should also start.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to add a shortcut to the Startup folder in your start menu, but if you don't want to do that you can use **regedit** to add a key to the registry at this location:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Also, if you want this to happen for any user that logs in to the system you do the same but add your key here instead:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

I think they are started in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1):

**[Quick Startup](http://www.glarysoft.com/qs.html?tag=download)** is free and easy to use.

[image: Quick startup screenshot]

Comment: Definitely nicer than the System Configuration program in Windows. Although, Quick Startup might be a bit overkill at times as it requires installation.

Comment: it does require an installation true.. but then its much easier and nicer to use

Comment: +1 @Rogue thanks for posting this, looks like a good app :)

Answer (score 1):

If your startup application needs elevated privileges, you can create a new task in Task Scheduler that runs a program at startup, with highest privileges. No UAC prompt this way, just one when you create the task.

Comment: There is a question covering this: http://superuser.com/questions/46/elevated-priviliges-for-startup-applications-in-vista

Comment: I actually added a similar answer to that as well, but I couldn't find that question when answering this one

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Win + R</kbd>, print **%APPDATA%/Microsoft/Windows/Start menu/Programs/Startup** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. New explorer window will be opened. Paste there shortcuts of programs you would like to start on logon.

To view complete list of programs that are configured to run during system bootup or login you could use free [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) program.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Start Menu, click on the Run command and in the box that will open type:

```
%HOMEPATH%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Paste or create any shortcuts that you want.