# Change Windows 7 user account control settings for a particular program

Tags: windows-7, uac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Elevated Priviliges for Startup Applications in Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/46/elevated-priviliges-for-startup-applications-in-vista)

I have a particular program that whenever I run it the screen dims and a message appears saying that the program wants to make changes to the computer and should I allow it.  I can make the message go away by lowering the user account control settings but I don't want to do it.  If other programs try to make changes to my computer, I want to be alerted.  However, I want to make an exception for this program so that it runs without having to alert me.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Elevated Priviliges for Startup Applications in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/46/elevated-priviliges-for-startup-applications-in-vista)

Comment: This should have been a comment.